# Startup issues with javascriptMVC

Tags: javascriptmvc

Ok, so this is a beginners question. I am trying to use the jQueryMX part of javascriptMVC. I have tried reading the docs, but I still have problems understanding the simplest things.

So I want to start my program with putting some data into my Model. My model should contain some tab data. I am currently not talking to server. I just want to start pumping the data some javascript.

So here is what I have come up with so far:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        tab = new Tabs({
            tab1: 
            {
                name:'Reuters',
                hits:'500'
            },
            tab2: 
            {
                name:'AP',
                hits:'5043'
            },
            tab3: 
            {
                name:'Sports',
                hits:'50'
            },
            tab4: 
            {
                name:'Cityscape',
                hits:'1'
            }
        });
    }
);

$.Model('Tabs',
{

},
{

}
);
```

Ok. So now I may/may not have pumped some data into my $.Model class. I don't have any functions or anything for it yet. I just want to be able to make sure I have the data in my class.

My questions are:
Are the data in my class or do I need to do more to it?
How can I find the data through the console?

I know this is begginners material. But I need this to get started, as the samples in their doc does not explain it good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code will not work. You are missing a lot of things actually.
For example your Model needs handlers for saving and reading data.

You should have a look at this example: http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!todo
It explains everything from creating a model with handlers and storing objects locally.

Also you should create your Apps and Models using the JS MVC generate function:

e.g. for creating a new app "foo" with the model "bar":

open a terminal and cd into your js mvc directory.

```
./js jquery/generate/app Foo
./js jquery/generate/model Foo.Bar
```

after executing these commands you should have a basic structure available.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. As stated in a previous answer, since the Tabs class does not implement the static service methods you will not be able to interact with the datasource (you won't be able to CRUD entities in any way that will persist once your objects are garbage collected). But, your code defines a `Tabs` class which inherits from `$.Model`, and instantiates it with some data.

From the console you can access the `tab` variable (since you've made it a global variable by not using `var`), use its attr or attrs methods and you will retrieve the data you used to create the `Tabs` instance. You could also bind event handlers to the instance, bind the model class to a jQuery element or anything the `$.Model` class provides for, except interacting with the datasource.

(I am ignoring any issues regarding the way you import the jQueryMX files themselves into your application.)